# AWS Codedeploy-agent deploys are using all of my inodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-14.04, inode, aws-code-deploy

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 trusty on an AWS EC2 c3.large instance.

My builds started failing with a 'No space left on device' error, even though `df` showed that my disk usage was nowhere near full.

I then figured out that it was a problem with my inodes by running `df -ih` and seeing that my inode usage was nearing 100% on `/dev/xvda1`.

I tracked the inode usage down to the codedeploy agent by using the following script to find directories with high inode usage `for i in /*; do echo $i; find $i |wc -l; done` by changing the `/*` to more specific directories to track down the specific problem.

Now I'm to the point where I'm in `/opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/aafbfc42-d92d-4260-be40-6c331a3c3a13` and each of the last 5 deployments that codedeploy keeps around are using ~70k inodes, most of which are due to the `node_modules` directory in my app, of which ~40k are used by `babel-preset-es2015`.

I'm not sure what the best way forward from here is.  Is that a normal amount of inodes for `babel-preset-es2015`?  Is there a way that I can safely delete either entire deployments or somehow not include `node_modules` in those deployments?  Is there some other solution I'm missing?

Thanks

**EDIT:** Looking a bit more into this. One of my production servers (same setup as the other) has 6.3M inodes whereas the problem server only has 512K inodes...

**EDIT2:** Looks like the one instance only has an 8GB volume attached to it whereas the other has a 100GB volume.  Still not exactly sure why the es2015 preset takes up so much space, but at least I know where to start fixing this now.

Answer (score 2):

Add a "AfterInstall" hook to your AppSpec file.

This might be an `rm -rf` on part of the /opt/codedeploy-agent tree ( like the node_modules directory ) or a `npm` command like `npm prune`

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue as well due to the default configuration of the CodeDeploy agent being to save 5 revisions of your app. Basically if you store `node_modules` in your app revision, e.g. if you need to run your Node app server-side, then its very easy to run out of disk for INodes.

I've decided to update my max revision configuration to 2 as I do not care about anything older than the previous iteration. One way to do this is to use sed + a user data script on your instance to override this.

```
# Example of user data script I added to find and replace config
sed -i 's/max_revisions: 5/max_revisions: 2/g' /etc/codedeploy-agent/conf/codedeployagent.yml
```

An alternative solutions would be to delete your `node_modules` (or npm prune) before the `DownloadBundle` stage so that you free up some space. Though be aware that this way somewhat limits the ability to run and debug an older deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of `:max_revisions:` in the `/etc/codedeploy-agent/conf/codedeployagent.yml` file:

```
]$ cat /etc/codedeploy-agent/conf/codedeployagent.yml
---
:log_aws_wire: false
:log_dir: '/var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/'
:pid_dir: '/opt/codedeploy-agent/state/.pid/'
:program_name: codedeploy-agent
:root_dir: '/home/ec2-user/'
:verbose: false
:wait_between_runs: 1
:proxy_uri:
:max_revisions: 2
```

(If you don't care about free tier and you have an EBS-backed volume attached to your instance, you could always detach it, increase its size, and reattach and remount the volume, as well.  That way you could keep the default 5 debug copies.)